# How do I test if list collides with point?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to test if a point "rect.midbottom" and a list "list" collide in PyGame. Here is the code I'm using now:

```
if pygame.Rect.collidelist(rect.midbottom, list) != -1:
    #yadda_yadda_yadda
```

What the terminal says:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'collidelist' for 'pygame.Rect' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object
```

What can I do to work around this?

Edit: The rect I'm referring to does not exist within the list, rather as its own object.

Comment: What do you mean by a "list" colliding with a point? A list is not a geometrical object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pygame, but from I can see, you should be using the `collidelist` from an instance of `Rect`, rather than passing the instance as a parameter to the method from the class `Rect`. Also, you shouldn't be using "list" as a variable name.

```
if rect.collidelist(list) != -1:
    #yadda_yadda_yadda
```

If you want to check just a single point, you can create a rectangle with all of its corners at `rect.midbottom`, or you can do

```
if any(rect_from_list.collidepoint(rect.midbottom) for rect_fram_list in list):
    #yadda_yadda_yadda
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the collidelistall function instead. It returns a list of all intersections.

```
index = rect.collidelistall(list)
if len(index) > 0:
    #yadda_yadda_yadda
```

EDIT (In response to the OP edit): because your rect is an object, this code would return an empty list. Instead, you should use

`index = rect.collidelist(list)`

If there is a collision, this will return the index of the first element in the list where the rectangle collides. If no collision occurs, returns -1.

Comment: Where exactly does rect.midbottom play into this? I'm trying to detect if a side of rect is being collided with, not the list.

Comment: Somewhere in the list is a Rect for each rectangle of the list. You can ask for the mid bottom of that Rect. If any of those mid bottoms collide with your rect's mid bottom, then your rect is colliding with something in the list.

The "problem" is that this way you have to loop through all the rects in the list and check them one by one, instead of just checking if your rect collides with anything. If you have an array like:

Comment: `list = [Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), Rect(1, 1, 1, 1)]`
then it's very fast to check if your rectangle collides with anything: a simple `rect.collidelist(list)` would do it and `rect.collidelistall(list)` would tell you which ones indeed collide with it. But if you want to know if any corner (or side) of your rectangle intersects with any corner (or side) of one of those 2 rects from before then things are different and this code will help you; if not you can use whatever loop suits you best.

Comment: I've edited OP so it makes more sense. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: i've edited my post